# What is the alternative for find in IE? Im getting this error TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm using 'find' in my code

```
var route = Object.keys(Routes).find(matchingLang)
```

It is not supporting in IE. In chrome and firefox it works fine.In IE , Its throwing this error `TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'`

This is my code

```
 var browLoc="en-GB"

    var Routes ={
                'en-*':'en_US',
                'es-*':'es_ES', 
                'pt-*':'pt_PT',
                'fr-*':'fr_FR',
                'de-*':'de_DE',
                'ja-*':'ja_JP',
                'it-*':'it_IT',
                 '*':'en_US'    
            }; 

    var matchingLang = function (route) {return new RegExp('^' + route.replace('*', '.*')).test(browLoc) }                          

    var route = Object.keys(Routes).find(matchingLang);
```

If i use 'filter' in place of find ,it returns all the matching values. I want only one output i.e only one Language value.

If anyone knows any alternative for this please do help.Thanks

Comment: You can check http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: You need to use a polyfill for IE. Find method is not supported in IE you can have look into this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: In this case i couldnt use document.querySelector(). What can i use for this scenario instead of 'find' ?

Comment: @radiance88 — Have you tried reading Raj's much upvoted comment?

Comment: @AnandSystematix — This has nothing to do with searching the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is not supported in IE. Not sure why you need to make it that complex. Just split and add the -* to it.

```
var browLoc="en-GB"

var Routes ={
            'en-*':'en_US',
            'es-*':'es_ES', 
            'pt-*':'pt_PT',
            'fr-*':'fr_FR',
            'de-*':'de_DE',
            'ja-*':'ja_JP',
            'it-*':'it_IT',
             '*':'en_US'    
        }; 

var lookup = browLoc.split("-")[0] + "-*";
var code = Routes[lookup] || Routes["*"];
console.log(code);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes it is simple